# Tips for getting LSTM to train for next word predcition

Tags: natural-language-processing, tensorflow, python, long-short-term-memory, keras

I am trying to train an LSTM network for next work prediction. I have scraped a rather large dataset from Wikipedia of country descriptions. I have done normal preprocessing (removing punctuation and contractions, etc.). The text is vectorized into integers with a vocab size of 1,000 and any words not in the most common 1,000 are replaced with `<unk>`. It is then batched into sequences of 128 words each and these are further split to provide variable sequence lengths to the model. In total, I end up with 2.1million sequences, obviously with considerable overlap.

An example of my data (prior to tokenization) is below:

```
['some', 'scholars', 'suggest', 'that'] -> 'the'
['some', 'scholars', 'suggest', 'that', 'the'] -> 'root'
['some', 'scholars', 'suggest', 'that', 'the', 'root'] -> 'name'
...
```

It is worth noting that the dataset contains many unknown words (about 30% of the total dataset is `<unk>`).

The model I am using is a simple LSTM:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model
class LSTMModel(Model):
    """A super simple LSTM model for history text generation"""
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim=256, lstm_units=512, num_layers=2,
                 bidirectional=False, num_dense_layers=2, hidden_dim=256, 
                 **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        
        # Embedding from vocab into embedding dimension
        self.embed = layers.Embedding(vocab_size + 1, embedding_dim)
        
        # LSTM layers
        lstm_layers = []
        for _ in range(num_layers - 1):
            local_layer = layers.LSTM(lstm_units, return_sequences=True)
            if bidirectional:
                local_layer = layers.Bidirectional(local_layer)
            lstm_layers.append(local_layer)
            
        # Add final layer
        final_layer = layers.LSTM(lstm_units, return_sequences=False)
        if bidirectional:
            final_layer = layers.Bidirectional(final_layer)
        lstm_layers.append(final_layer)
        self.lstm_layers = lstm_layers

        # Small MLP at the end
        self.head = MLP(num_dense_layers, vocab_size, hidden_dim)
        
    def call(self, x):
        # Mask zero values in input (ignored by LSTM)
        mask = utils.make_padding_mask(x)
        mask = tf.cast(mask, tf.bool)
        x = self.embed(x)
        for lstm in self.lstm_layers:
            x = lstm(x, mask=mask)
        return self.head(x)
```

This takes a sequence as input and returns a softmaxed vector over my vocabulary size. I am then using crossentropy to train to predict the next word correctly. But my loss decreases only a little at first and then stays quite high. The model learns to always predict "the" as the next word.

Why won't it learn anything? I have tried larger/smaller models (including a huge model with 30million parameters), playing with learning rate, using label smoothing, increasing vocab size, different sequence lengths, and nothing seems to work. Is this problem simply too hard? Is there something fundamentally flawed in my approach?

I'm learning NLP and would appreciate any insight.